# how to set dynamic endDate with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

how can i set an endDate that corresponds to the last day of the current year as i declare in my jquery code?.

it needs to be dynamic, because this will only work for 2022

```
$('.poll-calendar').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  startDate: "+1d", 
  daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
  endDate: new Date("2022-12-31"),
  language: 'es'
})
```

Comment: Use this const d = new Date();
let year = d.getFullYear(); and replace new Date("2022-12-31") with new Date(year+"-12-31")